# having emigrated VS. after emigrated

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, past-tense

My research is on Italian settlers to the countries of East Asia . I, however, don't intent comparing between the conditions of these people **having  emigrated** with their own condition in their country before emigrating.

By the bold part I mean after the people emigrated . Would you please correct me?

Comment: **"after emigrated** is wrong. You could use **after having emigrated**, though. But only using **having emigrated** here, **the conditions** *"(of these people)"* is not clear. What I mean is **"the condition** might refer to the state of those people either before **"emigration"** or after **"emigration"** or state at any point of time of their lives. But using **"after emigration"** or **"after being emigrated"** will narrow down the meaning of **their conditions**. Then it would mean clearly which condition at what point of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **after having emigrated** or **after emigrating**. Using "after" provides the right contrast to "before".

BTW, it's "I don't **intend** comparing..." (or better yet, "I don't **intend to compare...**").

Comment: I am not very comfortable with **after having emigrated**. What time it's talking about? If it's past, only "after" or "having" alone is sufficient, using both IMO is redundant.

Comment: As they continue to emigrate, the research might refer to those who recently emigrated as well as those who emigrated long ago. I  offered this as a less-worse alternative to OP's  unclear "having emigrated". But I, too, prefer the simple "after emigrating". This is the perfect counterpoint to "before emigrating".